# Run cleanup function at end of serverless function execution?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

If I don't close the DB connection at the end of my serverless function my script will hang and timeout.

I'm hoping there is a way I can run a clean up function at the end of any of my serverless functions which will close active DB connections etc.

```
module.exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {
  user.insert({
    //user details
  }).then((results) => {
    responseHelper.success(JSON.stringify(results), callback);
  }, (error) => {
    // Connection error
    responseHelper.error(error, callback);
  });

  // I don't want to have this at the end of every function
  // I'd rather run it in a cleanup step which runs on all functions
  db.closeConnections();
}
```

Comment: Or, you could try setting `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `user.insert()` returns a Promise and calling `db.closeConnections()` right after it may close the connection when you still need it. To achieve what you want to do, `db.closeConnections()` should be called just before the `callback` parameter.

Maybe you could call `db.closeConnections();` in your helper functions  `responseHelper.success()` and `responseHelper.error()`, before the execution of the `callback` parameter. I guess these functions are written only once and shared by all your lambda handler.

Comment: Ha, you're right. I hadn't actually ran the code at this point and I did have the db.closeConnections() statement in the wrong place.

Comment: And thanks for the suggestion. It's not exactly what I wanted, but it's good enough for now.